# how to convert text to speech using Twillio API in java & RestAPI

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, twilio

Hi i'm new to the Twilio api.

Can any one provide some ideas or good example for converting text to speech(voice).

I'm using java & Rest api & Twilio api.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio evangelist here.

The [`<Say>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say) TwiML verb does this for you:

```
<Response> 
    <Say>Hello World!</Say>
</Response>
```

I'd suggest working through the Voice Quickstart.  It walks you through using Java to build a servlet that generates and returns TwiML:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/java/twiml/say-response

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm sorry, but if you're evangelist, doesn't it seem to be weird to you? Let's suppose I write my custom web service which is hidden behind private network. Why should I expose anything outwards when I can just pass TwiML code inside POST body. What was the reason for doing such a non-intuitive API?

Answer (score 2):

`enter code here`When application initiates a call to the Twilio API, for example via the CallFactory.create method, Twilio will send your request to a URL that is expected to return a TwiML response.

The Say verb converts text to speech that is read back to the caller.  is useful for development or saying dynamic text that is difficult to pre-record.

Another option for responding with TwiML is via the TwiMLResponse class, which is available in the com.twilio.sdk.verbs package.

reference linK :  http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/partner-twilio-java-how-to-use-voice-sms/#howto_provide_twiml_responses

```
// Use your account SID and authentication token instead
// of the placeholders shown here.
String accountSID = "your_twilio_account";
String authToken = "your_twilio_authentication_token";

// Create an instance of the Twilio client.
TwilioRestClient client;
client = new TwilioRestClient(accountSID, authToken);

// Retrieve the account, used later to create an instance of the CallFactory.
Account account = client.getAccount();

// Use the Twilio-provided site for the TwiML response.
String Url="http://twimlets.com/message";
Url = Url + "?Message%5B0%5D=Hello%20World";

// Place the call From, To and URL values into a hash map. 
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("From", "NNNNNNNNNN"); // Use your own value for the second parameter.
params.put("To", "NNNNNNNNNN");   // Use your own value for the second parameter.
params.put("Url", Url);

// Create an instance of the CallFactory class.
CallFactory callFactory = account.getCallFactory();

// Make the call.
Call call = callFactory.create(params);
```

- sample code to generating the TWIML using TwiMLResponse class using
  inputMsgString :

  TwiMLResponse twiml = new TwiMLResponse();
          Say say = new Say( inputMsgString);
                  twiml.append(say);
              msgAsXML = twiml.toXML();